# Add margin to page content when absolute element is visible but keep centered

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page where the content is center `width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;`. I am adding a side bar (that shows/hides), it is absolutely positioned and I do not wish it to overlap the content. I have been trying various approaches to this issue, by adding padding and margin etc to the content, but nothing has the desired result as it currently pulls the content to the left when it should still remain centered.

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x06c3ysf/

```
$('#custom-sidebar').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hide');
    if ($(this).hasClass('hide')) {
        $('#inner').removeClass('adjust');
    } else {
        $('#inner').addClass('adjust');
    }
});

// run on page load
if ($('#custom-sidebar').hasClass('hide')) {
    $('#inner').removeClass('adjust');
} else {
    $('#inner').addClass('adjust');
}
```

Desired result:
The content is centered always on page resize, when the page is narrow enough to become obstructed by the sidebar, the page content should sit next to the sidebar.

Comment: This issue has a lot of people stumped, glad i'm not the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. You need to add a media query in to prevent the 'snapping action'

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x06c3ysf/7/

```
@media (max-width: 718px) {
    .adjust #inner {
        margin: 0 0 0 122px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is:

```
#inner {
width: 100%;
}
```

However, then the content is of the screen on the right side.

this seems to work, but probably not on all browsers:

```
#inner {
width: 100% -100px;
}
```

better resize the #inner width on toggleClass()

Comment: Personally I would use calc(), it works across all browsers minus Opera Mini: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: In your example the content is always 100% wide though. I need it 440px wide and centered.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the sidebar float. Remove the class "adjust"

```
#custom-sidebar {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height:300px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    float: left;
}

#inner.adjust {
    /*margin: 0 0 0 122px;*/
}
```

Did you like it?

Comment: It's overlapping the page still http://jsfiddle.net/x06c3ysf/4/ . Also, I do need to use position absolute given the complexity of the current markup. The fiddle is a simplified version. Thanks.

Comment: If you want different alignments when the window is wide enough and when the window too narrow, you may need a script to adjust the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is checking if left margin of the inner div is lesser than the width of sidebar and then only add class adjust

```
$('#custom-sidebar').on('click', function () {
    var margin_left = $('#inner').css('margin-left');
    var left_width = parseInt(margin_left.replace('px', ''));
    var sb_width = $('#custom-sidebar').width();
    $(this).toggleClass('hide');
    console.log(margin_left);
    console.log(left_width);
    console.log(sb_width);
    if ($(this).hasClass('hide')) {
        $('#inner').removeClass('adjust');
    } else {
        if (left_width <= sb_width) {
            $('#inner').addClass('adjust');
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x06c3ysf/5/)

Comment: It overlaps the content when the screen is narrowed, but thanks.